# Is PiBakery v2 a viable deployment solution for Pi4b running Dockerized NextCloud, PiVPN, PiHole, and more?

Tags: setup, puppet

I want to set up a couple of Raspberry Pi 4B devices for my home network next year. I need to get into automated deployment; devops; and CI/CD, so that my constant tinkering and tweaking can be reproducible, rather than relying so much on full backups. My skillbase is more from the "ops" side of devops though, so I'm considering learning [PiBakery](https://pibakery.org/) rather than Puppet, Terraform, or Ansible. My provisioning device is GNU/Linux based, so I'd need to install PiBakery from source, which is a skill I'm not overly confident with. I understand that PiBakery is similar to Scratch, which is aimed at children. If they can do it, then a senior citizen like myself should be able to!

What I am concerned about is that I see there has been no activity on the [PiBakery GitHub](https://github.com/davidferguson/pibakery) repository for over 3 years now. I see from a [search](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=pibakery) here that there are a few people using, or at least interested in, PiBakery. Does anyone know if it is still maintained?

Also, will PiBakery support deploying all of my desired applications? I have two 8GB RPi4B devices, and I want to set up one with PiVPN, PiHole, and NGINX Proxy Manager, and the other with NextCloud, a Wordpress blog, and Bitwarden server. Both devices should have Docker and Portainer on them. I assume that my PiBakery installation would only need to provision the OS image (and tweaks) plus Docker and Portainer, then the rest of the software can be orchestrated using those tools rather than PiBakery itself, right? Sorry, I am new to all of this, and I am trying to get it all straight in my head before I begin.

There is much for me to learn, in order to make this all work, and I want to get some guidance to be sure that I'll spend my time learning the applicable technologies, and not going off on a tangent or wasting my time with something that was never going to work as intended.

[image: A graphical representation of my planned network.]

Comment: If your goal is to develop DevOps skills that apply beyond the Pi I would suggest one of the more mainstream tools (puppet ansible etc.), not a Pi-specific tool.

Comment: No, my goal is devops for the sake of my own sanity. I'm retired, and don't need to upskill for employment reasons. I just see the need for devops in my own personal life. Being on the Autism Spectrum, I prefer order over chaos. My tweaking of my home computer network over the years thus far has been too chaotic, and my aging brain is forgetting what modifications I've made and how to reproduce them if needed. 

Comment: Actually, @SteveRobillard, your comment about "a Pi-specific tool" has got me to thinking now. In the longer term, once my RasPi's are all set up and working properly as intended, my next step will be to bring my client devices under a similar managed deployment system. Perhaps Puppet might be the better solution in the longer term? It is a steep initial learning curve for me, but I'd probably need to learn it anyway on top of PiBakery otherwise. I wonder if it can deploy to Android devices as well as GNU/Linux systems? Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now learning about Ansible for this purpose, as suggested in a comment by @SteveRobillard. As it turns out, PiBakery is no longer being maintained as a project on GitHub anyway.

Comment: If anyone is still interested in this, I came across an excellent resource to help with setting up a raspi using Ansible, as a post on opensource.com by Ken Fallon of Hacker Public Radio. See https://opensource.com/article/20/9/raspberry-pi-ansible

Comment: Following up again on this, I have since come across a post on PragmaticLinux.com which builds on the knowledge from Ken Fallon earlier, by describing how the latest Rasperry Pi Imager software now includes a hidden ability to set up SSH; change the hostname; and even change the default 'pi' user password of the raspi before burning the base image to the SD card. This makes it even easier to do now than Ken's manual method. See https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/08/raspberry-pi-headless-setup-with-the-raspberry-pi-imager/